# setting up NS for a new server

Tags: linux, domain-name-system, domain

i am a newbie in server administration.

i have a linux server which has a valid ip address.

now i want to register a domain and set that domain as my servers' NS.

but i dont know what should i enter for NS records when i want to register that domain.

i hope i am clear enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to configure "glue" records for your domain, which your registrar *should* permit.

i.e.:

```
ns1.example.com. IN NS w.x.y.z
```

(where `w.x.y.z` is the IP address of your Linux server)

These glue records, stored in the parent domain, solve the chicken-and-egg problem of how you find a nameserver within a particular domain, when you don't already know the address of that same nameserver.

Comment: so i have to ask my domain registrar to configure my domain's glue records. correct?

Comment: yes - they should be submitted at the point you register your domain.